# How to delete post in facebook by id using php, graph API

Tags: php, facebook, graph, facebook-apps

Can someone tell me how can I delete my own **posts** in **facebook** by **id** using **PHP** , **graph API**
I'd searched in **google** but I didn't find anything :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: For deleting Page Posts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/#Deleting

Comment: maybe this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#deleting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post#deleting

Important:

> An app can delete a post if it published it

Which means, you can NOT delete posts created without the App.